# Type 3 fonts in output PDF file

Tags: fonts, pdf

I am trying to submit an article through ScholarOne Manuscript Central. However, when I try to look at the PDF proof I get the Font Type 3 error.

I have used PDFLatex to compile the file, using *eps* images generated directly from Matlab, and some PDF figures generated from Visio.

From other posts, I have seen that it is advisable to export the images from Matlab to InkScape first. Is this necessary?

Besides, I have seen that you can use *pdffonts* to find all font types in the document and done so. From that file, I have the following fonts: 
Type 1, True Type, and CID True Type. Which ones are the Type 3 fonts?

Do you reckon I should just play with the Visio files or should I export the Matlab figures to InkScape first?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Full report from *pdffonts*:

```
    name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
DKVIYW+NimbusRomNo9L-Regu            Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       4  0
SQNDUJ+NimbusRomNo9L-ReguItal        Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       5  0
LREKMX+NimbusRomNo9L-MediItal        Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       6  0
ZISNES+NimbusRomNo9L-Medi            Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       7  0
DHGZIQ+CMMI10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no      14  0
VQSCDA+CMR10                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no      15  0
OIEZQV+CMR7                          Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no      16  0
GFKPTZ+CMMI7                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no      17  0
HIXHBR+CMSY10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no      18  0
SEMATC+CMEX10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no      19  0
ABCDEE+Calibri                       TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no      21  0
ABCDEE+TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT      TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no      22  0
ABCDEE+TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT      CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     23  0
ABCDEE+Calibri                       TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no      54  0
ABCDEE+Calibri-Bold                  TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no      55  0
ABCDEE+SymbolMT                      CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     56  0
ABCDEE+TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT        TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no      57  0
ABCDEE+MT-Extra                      CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     58  0
ABCDEE+TimesNewRomanPSMT             TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no      59  0
ABCDEE+TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT      TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no      60  0
PKRLSW+CMMIB10                       Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     103  0
EPUYGQ+NimbusMonL-Regu               Type 1            Custom           yes yes no     108  0
ABCDEE+Calibri-Italic                TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no     110  0
ABCDEE+Calibri                       TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no     111  0
ABCDEE+Calibri-Bold                  TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no     112  0
ABCDEE+Calibri                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    113  0
ABCDEE+Calibri-BoldItalic            TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no     114  0
BOOELT+CMMIB7                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     142  0
PXBGHL+CMSY7                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     143  0
HMCHKX+CMR5                          Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     144  0
ABCDEE+Calibri                       TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no     146  0
ABCDEE+TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT      TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no     147  0
ABCDEE+TimesNewRomanPSMT             TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no     148  0
ABCDEE+TimesNewRomanPS-BoldItalicMT  TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no     149  0
ABCDEE+Calibri-Italic                TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no     150  0
ABCDEE+TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT      CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    151  0
VOPKHO+CMR8                          Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     189  0
ZCBWGY+CMMI8                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     190  0
RGBZVD+CMR6                          Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     191  0
ABCDEE+Calibri-Bold                  TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no     206  0
ABCDEE+Calibri                       TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no     207  0
ABCDEE+TimesNewRomanPSMT             TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no     208  0
ABCDEE+TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT      TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no     209  0
ABCDEE+SymbolMT                      CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    210  0
ABCDEE+MT-Extra                      CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    211  0
Helvetica                            Type 1            Standard         no  no  no     248  0
Helvetica                            Type 1            Standard         no  no  no     251  0
Helvetica                            Type 1            Standard         no  no  no     254  0
Helvetica                            Type 1            Standard         no  no  no     257  0
RVPZIX+CMMI5                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     261  0
Helvetica                            Type 1            Standard         no  no  no     265  0
Helvetica                            Type 1            Standard         no  no  no     268  0
Helvetica                            Type 1            Standard         no  no  no     271  0
```

EDIT: here is the error message I get from Manuscript Central when I try to visualize the PDF proof:

*I received a Type 3 Font error during PDF creation. What should I do? 
A Type 3 font error is due to bit mapped fonts in your document or missing fonts used within the document. Bitmapped fonts display poorly on screen in PDF files and sometimes cause printing problems. We recommend for Word Documents that you embed your fonts and re-upload the file(s), or for PDF's save them using Acrobat 6 (or lower).
If your fonts are all uploaded to the manuscript or embedded, please also check the file name. If you have uploaded a TeX file and there are spaces in the file name, it will not convert. Remove the spaces in the file name and re-upload the file and the Type 3 Font error message should no longer display when you try to view the PDF.*

Comment: What's the error message exactly? Which PDF viewer were you using?

Comment: none of those are type 3 (it would say "Type 3" in the second column)

Comment: You are imho using too many different fonts. This combination of calibre, times, helvetica, computer modern etc probably doesn't look good.

Comment: I agree there are too many fonts, but that is mainly in the Visio images converted into PDFs and then embedded as figures. The overall result is not too bad, since the Latex text uses the same font + italics.

Comment: I have also included the error returned by Manuscript Central. I am not sure what PDF reader they used. I also converted the file to Adobe Reader 6 as suggested, as well as checking the file name. I still get the error. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: the full error message you quote says that it is bitmap or missing fonts, the only font not embedded in the list you show is helvetica, presumably that has come from some external image tool, try to get it to embed fonts

Comment: Thank you very much for spotting that! If you post a reply, I will vote it as the solution.

Comment: Helvetica means that the Matlab figures were the issue rather than the Visio diagrams as I expected. I guess I'll try to use Latex in the Matlab figures labels to see if it improves the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full error message you quote says that it is "bitmap or missing fonts", not just typ3 3 fonts that cause the warning.

The only font not embedded in the list you show is helvetica, presumably that has come from some external image tool, try to get it to embed fonts.